# Outlook Web Add-in: Can we add an entry into context menu?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I didn't find this functionality in Outlook web add-in documentation. But it's worth to ask...

We want to add a new entry into Outlook right click menu (context menu), so that it can open a hyperlink (url is different based on what you highlighted) to integrate with our web portal.

I understand [contextual outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/contextual-outlook-add-ins) is the closer solution.
But it's not the user experience we want.

Instead of highlight everything based on RegEx, we would like to support users to intentionally trigger the add-in by highlighted keyword and right click on the context menu.

Wondering if it's possible today for the latest Outlook desktop app.

User scenario:

1. User highlights a keyword in email reading/writing mode
2. User right click the mouse
3. The context menu shows up with having our custom menu item
4. When user clicks on our custom menu item, it opens a browser with an url based on what user highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook context menu cannot be extended at the moment. Available [extension points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/extensionpoint#extension-points-for-outlook) are:

- MessageReadCommandSurface
- MessageComposeCommandSurface
- AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface
- AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface
- Module (Can only be used in the DesktopFormFactor.)
- MobileMessageReadCommandSurface
- Events
- DetectedEntity

You probably should add your business case into Office development user voice request: [Outlook Web Add-in: Add Context Menu Mail Item Extension Point](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/35044528-outlook-web-add-in-add-context-menu-mail-item-ext) or at least upvote it.

Comment: Thanks, Slava. Do you know if Com add-in is still supported in Outlook desktop? It seems to me that Com add-in was able to customized context menu. But not sure if this tech is still supported or will be replaced by web add-in

Comment: @VivienHung The COM/VSTO add-ins are fully supported by Outlook desktop for Windows. Office JS add-ins are not the replacement for com technology, at least for now. Com add-ins are very robust and feature reach. For example, in your case, to add context menu is just a few lines of code. Please take a look on this article: [Selecting an API or technology for developing solutions for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/selecting-an-api-or-technology-for-developing-solutions-for-outlook). It feels like you'll benefit from reading this material.